# newbie: how can I include redirection in bash script?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am trying to write a one-line bash script on the bash command prompt that involves input redirection:

```
dbs$ for $f in *; do tr '\n' '' < $f; done
```

but the '<' character is causing problem. Do I need to escape the < character somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should read

```
dbs$ for f in *; do tr '\n' '' < $f; done
```

The `for` builtin binds the respective values that are being iterated (i.e., `*`) to the variable, so you cannot ask bash to expand the variable right after `for`.

---

After your Edit; The script looks fine. Your problem are being caused somewhere else.

For one thing, your invocation of `tr` looks wrong: You probably meant `tr -d '\n'`.